# K-fold crossvalidation on images

Tags: keras, deep-learning

Let's say I have some pictures divided in 3 categories ("cat", "dog", "mouse") and my DL net is written in keras.
The design I used is the same as in this picture (1):

[image: Picture 1]

I splitted the data into three different folders: training, validation and test.
The net should be able to recognize a cat, dog or a mouse given a picture. The accuracy I get is around 98%.

It works.
But I need for some reasons change that design. I would like to use the K-fold cross-validation process and the schema should now look like (2):

[image: Picture 2]

Now my problem is that I don't know how to split and distribute the original data according to the schema in Fig. 2.

I can only imagine 2 different ways. Let's forget the test directory for the moment:

1. I create 2 folders: "Training" and "Validation". In both is the structure the same as in Fig. 1: Three subdirectory for every categories. Now the problem is: should I move the data around when progressing from *Fold 1* to *Fold 3*? Or I can allocate once the images into the subdirectories?
2. I create 2 folders: "Training" and "Validation", BUT I mix all images togheter. No subdirectory. In this case I have the problem that I lose the connection between the picture name and the pet on it. How can I tell Keras, which animal should be identified?

Personally I would mix all images togheter, no matter what they show. But I would save the information of the content into a file. In this case I pass to Keras the directory (Validation or Training) and a file containing the name of all files and their content.

What would you suggest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I can answer my own question.

The easiest way is just to user `Kfold` form `sklearn` in the python script

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
```

After that you need to istantiate KFold

```
kfold = KFold(n_splits = 4, shuffle = True)
```

and you iterate over the splitted dataset like:

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1. / 255.)


for train, test in kfold.split(df_data):
    
    # df is the whole dataset (all together!)
    df_train = df.iloc[train, :]  # Look that train is coming from the for in .. loop
    df_test  = df.iloc[test, :]  # The same for test

    train_generator = datagen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe = df_train,
                                                  directory = dataset_dir,
                                                  ... )

    test_generator = datagen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe = df_test,
                                                 directory = dataset_dir,
                                                 ...)


    model = models.Sequential()
    .....

    model.compile(...)
    model.fit(...)
```

and it is done! The dataset is now splitted in partitions!!!
**Note** that the class ImageDataGenerator is not in the for loop!!!
And **note** please, that the methods (model `creation, compile() and fit()`) **must** **be** in the for-loop.

The code above works for me very good.

Comment: Hello, "df_data" is a dataframe that contains the images path or you are saving the images in dataframe rows?

Comment: 'df_data' is a dataframe containing the path to the images. E.g.: for one row:
/usr/dataset/train/class_a/image.jpg

Comment: Great! Thanks Dave. By the way, the "test_generator" partition here shouldn't be called "validation_generator"?

For others like me, if it's useful: [full implementation](https://medium.com/the-owl/k-fold-cross-validation-in-keras-3ec4a3a00538)